# Ionic - disallow_useragent issue on trying to Gmail Oauth login in IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, oauth

I am trying to implement Gmail OAuth login in Android and iOS using the Ionic framework.
I am not able to login with Gmail OAuth in iOS. It is working fine in android.
It is causing issue only in iOS.
[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue with Gmail OAuth in Ionic app in iOS.

Comment: are you using ng-cordova-oauth?

Comment: Yes, I am using ng-cordova-oauth.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't allow webview login any longer.

The best way to go about it is to use the following plugins:
Google: https://github.com/ionicthemes/google-login-with-ionic-framework
Googleplus: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus